# Angular2 dynamically adding divs

Tags: angular

I have an input box where I will specify a number like 3 or 4 and below it I have a parent div. As per the number specified in the input box I want to have that many divs inside parent.

```
        <div class="mdl-step__content">
            <!-- specify number -->
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="text5">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="text5">Number of important collegues</label>
                <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Number required!</span>
            </div>
            <!-- circular divs -->
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I achieve it?

UPDATE:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ngFor` for this purpose:

```
<input ngModel (ngModelChange)="updateNumber($event)" class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="text5">

<div class="parent">
  <div class="circle" *ngFor="let item of items"></div>
```

```
updateNumber(val:number) {
  this.items = new Array(+val);
}
```

Comment: should it be: `new Array(val)`? also I had to remove set from the function. However, it do not let me add  `*ngFor="let item in items"` on that div. It says : Property binding ngForIn not used by any directive on an embedded template.

Comment: Wow, sorry! Seems to one of my more sloppy answers. It should be `of` instead of `in`.

Comment: Now it does not give any errors, but whatever number I enter, it gives me just one div. Adding image to my question!

Comment: Use `new Array(+val)` to ensure it's treated as number. https://plnkr.co/edit/beg2B5eQYGa2a5Zj0Azm?p=preview

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! Thanks a lot :)